# SignTool Error: File not found - pfx

Tags: .net, windows, signing, codesign, authenticode

I am using `signtool.exe` to sign binaries with the [PFX](http://www.tech-pro.net/export-to-pfx.html) file.

But when I try to execute the command through command line, an error message is displayed.

`SignTool Error: File not found: D:\Myfile.Pfx`
But the file `D:\Myfile.Pfx` exists at that location. 
 
 
I tried signing files using the latest version of [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but the problem persists. 
I am using Windows XP SP3 32 bit.

Any idea on the reason for this error and how do I rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

try giving a  echo statement before the actual signing which not only gives you a chance to review the command being used but also giving signtool enough time (delay) which sometimes fixes this issue. It may not be a wrong command or file not existing but could be a timing issue as well with a vague error code returned.